# Using Required (html5) in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, internet-explorer, html-helper

I'm trying to use a required property for a textbox in my page but my problem is that it is a 
html5 attribute, is there any fix or alternate for this?

How i create my TextBox

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SubChoiceText, new { @class ="ui-textbox",required = "required" })
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a required data annotation. If you are using jQuery and the unobtrusive validation, this performs client-side validation on the required element when you submit the form.

In your model

```
[Required]
public string SubChoiceText { get; set; }
```

In your view

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubChoiceText, new { @class = "ui-textbox" })
```

If you are using mvc4 see: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model